# Using le or ge with scalar left hand side creates unsized formula array

Tags: python-3.x, drake

When creating a formula with `le` or `ge` with a scalar left hand side, the returned formula has `.shape == ()`, i.e. is an unsized object.  This causes problems when adding a constraint with the formula.

I'm not sure if this is a bug.

```
prog = MathematicalProgram()
q = prog.NewContinuousVariables(1, 'q')
z = prog.NewContinuousVariables(2, 'z')
r = prog.NewContinuousVariables(rows=2, cols=3, name='r')
constraint = prog.AddConstraint(le(q, r[0,2] + 2*r[1,0])) # works
constraint2 = prog.AddConstraint(z[1] <= r[0,2] + 2*r[1,0]) # works
# constraint2 = prog.AddConstraint(le(z[1], r[0,2] + 2*r[1,0])) # fails
constraint2 = prog.AddConstraint(le([z[1]], r[0,2] + 2*r[1,0])) # works

formula = le(z[1], r[0,2] + 2*r[1,0])
print(formula.shape)
# > ()
```

Comment: Hi Rufus! It sometimes (read: almost always) muddies the water when you post an issue about an error, but only state that it "fails" without expanding on the error message. Can you post the error message here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL;DR

For now, your available workarounds:

- Reformulate to be strictly vector-valued (as you had done)
- Pass the direct object value (using [`ndarray.item`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html))
- Reshaping / unsqueeze the scalar array into a 1-d array

Will also post Drake issue.

### Longform

Soonho's post is generally correct, with some minor corrections:

1. `le(x, y)` is another way of writing `np.asarray(x) <= np.asarray(y)`. (See: [drake#11171](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/11171), [`numpy.vectorize` docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html))
2. While it is true that it isn't iterable, that's not the important part. The more important part is that `<Formula>` object output gets wrapped into a "scalar array" `array(<Formula>, dtype=object)`.
3. As mentioned, this is a 0-dimensional array (empty shape); however, "empty array" may be a bit of a misnomer, since it has data. You can retrieve contents by using `np.item()`
4. Also correct. However, the nuance here is that `np.vectorize` will return "scalar arrays", and those in turn cannot be interpreted by our Python bindings using `pybind11`.

For point (4), I re-ran your example on the nightly `drake-20201104-bionic.tar.gz`, and got this error message:

```
TypeError: AddConstraint(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self: pydrake.solvers.mathematicalprogram.MathematicalProgram, func: function, lb: numpy.ndarray[numpy.float64[m, 1]], ub: numpy.ndarray[numpy.float64[m, 1]], vars: numpy.ndarray[object[m, 1]], description: str = '') -> drake::solvers::Binding<drake::solvers::Constraint>
    2. (self: pydrake.solvers.mathematicalprogram.MathematicalProgram, arg0: pydrake.symbolic.Expression, arg1: float, arg2: float) -> drake::solvers::Binding<drake::solvers::Constraint>
    3. (self: pydrake.solvers.mathematicalprogram.MathematicalProgram, arg0: pydrake.symbolic.Formula) -> drake::solvers::Binding<drake::solvers::Constraint>
    4. (self: pydrake.solvers.mathematicalprogram.MathematicalProgram, constraint: drake::solvers::Constraint, vars: numpy.ndarray[object[m, 1]]) -> drake::solvers::Binding<drake::solvers::Constraint>
    5. (self: pydrake.solvers.mathematicalprogram.MathematicalProgram, formulas: numpy.ndarray[object[m, n], flags.f_contiguous]) -> drake::solvers::Binding<drake::solvers::Constraint>
Invoked with: <pydrake.solvers.mathematicalprogram.MathematicalProgram object at 0x7f6eb081cdf0>, array(<Formula "(z(1) <= (2 * r(1,0) + r(0,2)))">, dtype=object)
```

The most important thing to note is that overload (3) could have caught a raw scalar `<Formula>`, and (5) could have catch a 1- or 2-dimensional array, but neither are set up to catch `array(<Formula>)`.

This is more-or-less a `pydrake` and/or `pybind11` issue. I will file a Drake issue for now.

---

FWIW I've posted a NumPy issue asking about the right terminology for a 0-dim array: 
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/17744

Comment: Posted issue: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/14305

Answer (score 2):

1. `le(x,y)` is another way of writing `np.array(x <= y)`.
2. `x <= y` forms a symbolic formula which is not *iterable*.
3. As a result, `np.array(x <= y)` creates an empty array. You can tell this by checking its shape (`()`) or trying `np.array(x <= y)[0]` (which gives you an error).
4. This is not Drake-symbolic specific. `np.array(42)` gives you an empty array.